# Footable attributes lost when using VueJS v-if false / true

Tags: jquery, vue.js, footable

I have a table that use [Jquery footable](https://fooplugins.com/plugins/footable-jquery/). I didn't find an equivalent with VueJS.

Now, I want to delete / restore row in the table, when I delete a row, with

```
$vm0.isVisible = false; // ( Each row is a vue component )
```

with:

```
<tr v-if="isVisible">...</tr>
```

and then I show it again with :

```
$vm0.isVisible = true;
```

Row appears, but lose all footable attributes ( `data-toggle="true"`, `data-hide="all"` ,etc. )

Anybody knows why is it happening, and if there is something to do about that???

Answer (score 1):

Vue.js uses [Virtual-Dom](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom) to perform dom manipulations. So your html elements are actually javascript objects before rendering.

For example,
the `<tr>` element (as a virtual dom element) is perhaps an object like this:

`{tagName: 'tr', props: {class: 'table-row'}, children: []}`

The above object will be finally rendered into `<tr class="table-row">`.

However in jQuery Footable, the `<tr>` element is just a dom tag with props like `data-toggle` etc in it which all props are controlled by jQuery instead of Vue.js. Vue doesn't know anything about these props (`data-toggle` sort of things) created by jQuery. So when you use `v-if` or `v-show` to make anything appear again, it will only be recovered into a 'Vue type of Element'.

You may create a cool responsive table by using flex-box design and it is very easy to learn.

If you don't want to write yourself a responsive table by flex-box or whatsoever, you may want to give a try on ElementUI / iView / Vue Material / (Awesome Vue has many useful repositories).

Good luck! Hope you can make it!

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect Vue to live happily with other dom-manipulators. Vue strips event listeners when it mounts on an element. Then it will happily overwrite the parts of the dom it is responsible for, whenever it decides it needs to. If you can't live without legacy javascript, you need to get it to run after Vue has mounted. You're trying the opposite trick, with little Vues running inside a table managed by footable. This will never work.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't find an equivalent with VueJS.

have you tried https://github.com/ratiw/vue-table?
i think it is similar to footable